# Ugly font on Google Search via Safari

Tags: macos, safari, font

I've already tried clearing cache, resetting fonts and rebooting the system.
I only see that font in google searches. What can I do ?

macOS Sonoma 14.1 (23B74) | Safari Version 17.1 (19616.2.9.11.7).

[image: ugly font in search]

Comment: That seems strange. Have you checked for browser extensions, Safari's font and language settings (sorry I'm not in front of Safari at the moment), completely deinstalling and reinstalling Safari (https://support.apple.com/downloads/safari)? Does it only happen in Safari?

Comment: In private mode works fine. Hm 
No extension's, English, default settings.

Comment: Solved: Just clear cache + cookie from google, include `fonts.google` 

Comment: @NickRossik It would be great if you could leave an answer with that and explaining how you did it, to mark the question as answered and help other people looking for the solution!

Comment: @OleHansson - you can't uninstall Safari. It simply won't let you - nor would it gain anything. The app itself is protected & inviolable. Extensions/cache etc is a different matter. [Generally, reinstalling an app - one that can be - is a complete waste of time, because it's not the app at fault, it's a pref/extension/cache that has gone awry. The reinstall myth comes from Windows users, also unaware of how this structure functions in general, but also because *some* Windows uninstallers actually *do* remove prefs as a well. Uninstall on Mac doesn't do this.]

Answer (score 2):

Don't do that! The bug will come back once re-connected (and you will lose two-factor auth cookies).
Instead create a CSS file containing:

```
.LC20lb {
  -webkit-text-stroke: unset !important;
}
```

save it somewhere on your Mac and load it in **Safari settings > Advanced > Stylesheets**.

Comment: this infact solved the issue, as once I relogin to gmail the problem was back even after clearing cache.

Is this some google's revenge for content-block in safari? no other website seems to have this issue

Comment: I think it's a bug since the LC20lb class has the `-webkit-text-stroke: 0.2px;` property in normal browsing but not in private browsing.

Comment: This seems to have helped with the issue in Google searches. But there's still an issue when the Safari tried to display other graphics.

Comment: I can reproduce the issue by going to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moving_average) and looking the LateX formulas, 
[Safari vs Chrome LateX rendering](https://imgur.com/a/XtqjJwo)

Comment: so, bug is back :( i guess the LC20lb is not the only class or google somehow changes the name dynamicly, now it appears on .vG8NC

Answer (score 1):

What worked for me was checking "Disable Full Page Accelerated Drawing" on the Debug > Drawing/Compositing Flags menu in Safari, as mentioned at [Is there a way I can fix mathjax font on safari so that it's not blurry and fuzzy? It only happens on safari and it seems to only be affecting my safari as none of my other friends seem to have this problem](https://www.reddit.com/r/MacOS/comments/zz9yjh/comment/jaose5y/).

To activate the Debug Menu, input the following command in your terminal (ensure that Terminal.app or iTerm.app has Full Disk access; otherwise, an error will occur):

```
defaults write com.apple.Safari IncludeInternalDebugMenu 1
```

Comment: This seems to have fixed the issue for me! 
For reference, I had no error when inputting the command above (even though I didn't have Full Disk access enabled for Terminal), but until I gave terminal Full Disk access, Safari didn't show up the Debug menu.

Comment: Until macOS 10.14 (Mojave), there was an option in the Settings section of Safari to manage hardware acceleration. Also need a full disk permission.

Answer (score 0):

Solution is to clear cache and cookies:

1. Open Safari Settings via <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>,</kbd>
2. Goto Privacy tab, at the very bottom, click on **Manage Website Data…**

   [image: Privacy tab]
3. In search just type `google`. You will see all matches, for example: `fonts.googleapis.com`

   [image: Search for google]
4. Click to **Remove All**, then **Remove Now** (in my example, there are 13 sites with the word "google" in them).

   [image: Remove all action]
5. That's all. Try to open a Google search again and you'll see a regular font.

Comment: This fixes it only temporarily, once i logged back to gmail it was all back